# How to handle button on windows form reversed when press arrow key on keyboard using powershell?

Tags: powershell, winforms, user-interface, button, reverse

I have windows form with 3 button function. But the button reversed when I press the arrow key on keyboard.

This is the style of the button I have for all the buttons.

```
$Test= New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
$Test.BackColor = "$Dark"
          $Test.ForeColor = "$White"
          $Test.AutoSize = $true
          $Test.Text = "BUTTON 1"
          $Test.Add_Click(
               {
                 }
```

[image]

this is the button looks like, it always start on button 2. if I press left arrow key, it will go to button 3, but it supposed go to button 1. If I press right arrow key, it will go to button 1, but it supposed go to button 3.

Anyone can give me idea please, should I add another function to solve the reversed problem? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It supposed to order the button control from button 1, button 2 and button 3

Comment: This behavior is governed by the TabIndex Property. Make sure your Buttons have a progressive TabIndex and that no other Control in the same Container uses the same indexes.